# Cómo sé cuando hacer una subquerry en MySQL

Tags: mysql

¿hay alguna pista en los enunciados de los problemas donde se de un indicio de la necesidad de realizar una subquerry en SQL?

Comment: un buen momento para leer [referencia](http://www.v-espino.com/~chema/daw1/tutoriales/SQL2.pdf) basicamente cuando necesitas hacer algo que no puedas determinar en la query principal.

Comment: Pues cuando la necesites... :) Sé que suena evidente pero es así. Si todas las consultas se pudieran hacer sin subqueries, nadie las usaría. Y de los enunciados nunca te fíes: a veces los enunciados simples esconden consultas muy complejas... Te animo a estudiar algo de álgebra relacional para que veas cómo se construye una query de forma lógica, a veces el SQL se hace cuesta arriba porque le pedimos cosas que no se pueden hacer en un único paso

Comment: perfecto, gracias a ambos

Comment: La pregunta es amplísima, pero muy interesante, aunque lamentablemente no se adapta al formato del sitio por lo ya dicho, demasiado amplia. [Aquí tienes un punto de partida](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html). Si te queda alguna duda concreta, no dudes en preguntar, luego de haber investigado/probado, pero exponiendo el problema concreto, pues el tema de las subconsultas da para mucho, como verás en el enlace y enlaces relacionados allí.